# Import web parts from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I have five custom web parts in SharePoint 2013. Is it possible to export these and then import them into SharePoint online?

OR is there another way to add custom web parts to SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

What type of web parts are we talking?

Most likely you will need to transform your web parts to SharePoint Framework web parts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

You might also find these articles here  interesting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/from-app-parts-to-modern-web-parts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/from-sharepoint-hosted-to-client-side